# How to Render HTML entities string in Vash File with NodeJs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I am not able to get Hello world in vash file in below code:-

```
var result = {"description" : "<H1>Hello world</H1>"};
res.render('home',{data:result});

In home.vash  
@modal.data.description
The out put is  
<H1>Hello world</H1>
but I want only Hello world with html entity properties
```

Answer (score 0):

When you passed data from node js to any html compiled file like .vash or .ejs, data will be passed as string. Data will not render as html tag.

```
    var result = {"description" : "Hello world"};
    res.render('home',{data:result});
```

`In home.vash` 

write your .vash code `@modal.data.description` inside the html tag